# PHP Error: Class 'App\News' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I try to run the following

```
>>> $news = new App\News();
```

I'm getting the following error in tinker

```
PHP Error:  Class 'App\News' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the complete path as follows:

```
>>> $news = new App\Models\News();
```